# XPathAPI Jar for Android

Tags: android, xpath, xpath-api

Am using vzaar Android API to upload videos. The vzaar contains XPathAPI for that I included

```
jaxb-xalan-1.5 with that it working fine android 2.2 and above.
```

But When I about to install in `2.1 or 1.6`, app not installing.

It simply throws `Linearalloc memory error and closes...`

Is there any Similar external jars as jaxb-xalan-1.5, which support all android firmware?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting the LinearAlloc error messages when dexopt:ing the application? And, is it the "LinearAlloc exceeded capacity" error you're getting?

Comment: Yes am getting LinearAlloc error messages, when am deploying after adding jaxb-xalan-1.5 jar..

Comment: That could be because of a known "feature" of dalvik/dexopt, the issue is still there in some form for 2.3 (bug #22586), but it could very well be more severe for earlier versions of Android. If this is the case you are s.o.l unless you manage to reduce the complexity of jaxb-xalan-1.5 or find someone who has already done the legwork for you.

Comment: Yes, am looking for similar jars,which less size ! reduce the cmplexity ? http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is Java API lib 2.0 is listed on http://code.google.com/p/vzaar/downloads/list Did you checked this one?